# Matrix multiplication using MATLAB

Tags: matlab

If i have the following matrix:

```
a=[10   1   0   1   1
   50   1   0   0   0
   60   0   0   0   1]
```

how can i multiply first column in the matrix [10 50 60]' as vector multiplication to the rest of the matrix and get the following:

```
b=[10  10  0  10  10
   50  50  0   0   0
   60  0   0   0   60]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to frame it as a matrix multiplication, something like:

```
b = [a(:,1), diag(a(:,1))*a(:,2:end)]
```

should work (it's been a while since I've done any matlab, though).

Comment: Your answer seems to be the most straightforward one, firm connections to linear algebra as well. I skimmed the answers too hastily and wouldn't even posted my own one if I just had recognized your answers superiority at first sight.

Answer (score 5):

For this, `bsxfun`is what you need:

```
b = [a(:,1) bsxfun(@times,a(:,2:end),a(:,1))]
```

hope this helps,

A.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, this should be the accepted answer +1

Answer (score 2):

```
firstcol = a(:,1);
b = [firstcol, a(:,2:end) .* repmat(firstcol,1,size(a,2)-1)];
```

(This really isn't the sort of thing we normally call vector multiplication or matrix multiplication though.)